# Django Rest Framework - How to POST foreign keys in ListCreateAPIView

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework

**Post** model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Profile is another model
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    subreddit = models.ForeignKey(Subreddit, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Subreddit is another model
```

**PostSerializer**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

**ListPostsOfReddit**

```
class ListPostsOfReddit(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(subreddit__name=self.kwargs['r_name'])
```

In the `ListCreateAPIView` of **rest-framework**, I am able to **GET** all the foreign key data. In the form that **rest-framework** provides, only the

- Title
- Content
- Votes

are asked, I want the **foreign key fields** to be also asked as input. How do I achieve that?

Comment: It can be achieved by removing `depth = 1` from the serializer. **But, you will not get the serialized information related to FKs**

Comment: Ya, I want those details during **GET**. Is there no other way around?

Comment: I added one answer. Please do try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Two serializers, and manage those in `get_serializer()` method.

```
class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
class ListPostsOfReddit(ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            return PostListSerializer
        return PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(subreddit__name=self.kwargs['r_name'])
```

Note: I didn't tested/verified the solution. Please let me know if any error occured